# does an ip address have multiple ports?

Tags: networking

I have read somewhere that "if you are the remote user connecting to a web server, then your web browser would pick a random TCP port from a certain range of port numbers, and attempt to connect to port 80 on the IP address of the web server". Does that mean that a particular ip address at client side have multiple ports?

Comment: Technically, ports have nothing to do with IP addresses. IP addresses are at layer 3 in the OSI model. Ports are layer-4 addresses which _some_ layer-4 protocols use. TCP and UDP are the two most discussed layer-4 protocols, and they have addresses called ports, but there are other layer-4 protocols, too, and some don't even use ports. It all depends on which layer-4 protocol your application is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every system which implements TCP/IP has multiple "ports".  The IP address refers to the entire system, if that's all we had it would be pretty boring.  One program on a system could talk to one program on another system.

Hence the idea of "ports".  Ports are just a 16-bit number which "completes" the address.  So, your program on system 1.2.3.4 wants to talk to the webserver running on 2.3.4.5. The webserver "binds" itself to port 80.  This is an example of a "well known port".  But, how is the webserver to get data back to you?  Your program needs a "port" of its own.  But, it can be any old number, it doesn't need to be well known, so it just tells the OS I need a port and the OS finds one not in use and your program is "bound" to that port.  Say it is port 3456.

So now we have all we need: 1.2.3.4:3456 can talk to 2.3.4.5:80
and when the packets of data for port 80 arrive at 2.3.4.5, the OS delivers them to the webserver.  And when the packets of data for port 3456 arrive back at your computer (1.2.3.4), your OS delivers them to your web browser.

Comment: Thanks for that kind explanation..

Answer (score 1):

Whereever you read that, it's wrong. The *TCP implementation* picks a random local port. Not the browser. There are 65535 TCP ports per IP address, and another 65535 UDP ports.

Comment: "There are 65535 ports per IP address:" wrong. There are 65,535 TCP ports, OK, and 65,535 UDP ports = 131,070 ports per IP.